# Grunt - wiredep changes bower dependencies

Tags: gruntjs, wiredep

Wiredep is altering the bower dependencies in index.html.
It changes `bower_components/modernizr/modernizr.js`
to

```
../../../bower_components/modernizr/modernizr.js
```

Why is it doing this? How to change it?

```js
wiredep: {
    app: {
        src: ['src/main/webapp/index.html'],
        exclude: [/angular-i18n/, /swagger-ui/]
    },
    test: {
        src: 'src/test/javascript/karma.conf.js',
        exclude: [/angular-i18n/, /swagger-ui/, /angular-scenario/],
        ignorePath: /\.\.\/\.\.\//, // remove ../../ from paths of injected javascripts
        devDependencies: true,
        fileTypes: {
            js: {
                block: /(([\s\t]*)\/\/\s*bower:*(\S*))(\n|\r|.)*?(\/\/\s*endbower)/gi,
                detect: {
                    js: /'(.*\.js)'/gi
                },
                replace: {
                    js: '\'{{filePath}}\','
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Wiredep adds the '../../../' if your index.html file is nested in another folder.

For example my index.html is within my templates/src/index.html

As should be your bower_components should be in your **root** file so wiredep would be linking the files correctly if your setup is like the above.
If not you need to indicate to wiredep where your index.html path is when you run wiredep.

Again my example I run wiredep --src templates/src/assets/index.html

Using the wiredep CLI this is easier to do if you just use the command line to link rather than gulp.

Looking at your src location wiredep is linking the files correctly if your bower_components are where they should be in the root of your work directory.